# Group by minimum value in one field while selecting distinct rows

Tags: sql, group-by, max, distinct, min

Here's what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have this table t:

```
key_id | id | record_date | other_cols
1      | 18 | 2011-04-03  | x
2      | 18 | 2012-05-19  | y
3      | 18 | 2012-08-09  | z
4      | 19 | 2009-06-01  | a
5      | 19 | 2011-04-03  | b
6      | 19 | 2011-10-25  | c
7      | 19 | 2012-08-09  | d
```

For each id, I want to select the row containing the minimum record_date. So I'd get:

```
key_id | id | record_date | other_cols
1      | 18 | 2011-04-03  | x
4      | 19 | 2009-06-01  | a
```

The only solutions I've seen to this problem assume that all record_date entries are distinct, but that is not this case in my data. Using a subquery and an inner join with two conditions would give me duplicate rows for some ids, which I don't want:

```
key_id | id | record_date | other_cols
1      | 18 | 2011-04-03  | x
5      | 19 | 2011-04-03  | b
4      | 19 | 2009-06-01  | a
```

Comment: If there is a `min_by` function, consider it for this purpose. It saved me from writing something more complicated.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

How about something like:

```
SELECT mt.*     
FROM MyTable mt INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, MIN(record_date) AS MinDate
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY id
    ) t ON mt.id = t.id AND mt.record_date = t.MinDate
```

This gets the minimum date per ID, and then gets the values based on those values. The only time you would have duplicates is if there are duplicate minimum record_dates for the same ID.

Comment: Ah, initially I was using an expression to output a date which was causing the 'and' condition on the inner join to not work properly. Changed it to an actual column and it works now (and had to modify some other things as a result), thanks!

Comment: this would not work when two records of same id and date are present, will get you multiple rows right?

Answer (score 15):

I could get to your expected result just by doing this in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql):

```
 SELECT id, min(record_date), other_cols 
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY id
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: For whatever reason, this appears to work in the contrived example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8469/6/0), but in practice I get "Column 'database.table.col_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I was able to get it working with astander's answer anyway, thanks.

Comment: Yeah I'm running into the same issue, I'd like a simple answer like this one on SQL Server

Comment: Newer MySQL versions will raise an error here. (Unless in compatibility mode. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by.)

Comment: The reason this works or worked in older versions of MySQL is that MySQL would just give you arbitrarily the first values it encounters (maybe based on insertion order or whatever) for the non-grouped-by columns. This is really arbitrary and this is why other DBMSes don't do this, and apparently MySQL also chose to do the right thing.

Comment: sorry, I think it's misleading and should not be used, as this should be an undefined behavior in any DBMS

Answer (score 10):

To get the cheapest product in each category, you use the  MIN() function in a correlated subquery as follows:

```
    SELECT categoryid,
       productid,
       productName,
       unitprice 
    FROM products a WHERE unitprice = (
                SELECT MIN(unitprice)
                FROM products b
                WHERE b.categoryid = a.categoryid)
```

The outer query scans all rows in the products table and returns the products that have unit prices match with the lowest price in each category returned by the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add to some of the other answers here, if you don't need the *first* item but say the second number for example you can use rownumber in a subquery and base your result set off of that.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUM() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY record_date, other_cols) as rownum,
        *
    FROM products P
) INNER
WHERE rownum = 2
```

This also allows you to order off multiple columns in the subquery which may help if two record_dates have identical values. You can also partition off of multiple columns if needed by delimiting them with a comma

Answer (score 3):

This does it simply:

```
select t2.id,t2.record_date,t2.other_cols 
from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by record_date)as rownum,id,record_date,other_cols from MyTable)t2 
where t2.rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## If `record_date` has no duplicates within a group:

think of it as of filtering. Simpliy get (WHERE) one (`MIN(record_date)`) row from the current group:

```
SELECT * FROM t t1 WHERE record_date = (
                                 select MIN(record_date)
                                 from t t2 where t2.group_id = t1.group_id)
```

---

## If there could be 2+ min `record_date` within a group:

1. filter out non-min rows *(see above)*
2. then (AND) pick only one from the 2+ min `record_date` rows, within the given `group_id`. E.g. pick the one with the min unique key:

   ```
                   AND key_id = (select MIN(key_id)
                                 from t t3 where t3.record_date = t1.record_date
                                             and t3.group_id    = t1.group_id)
   ```

so

```
key_id | group_id | record_date | other_cols
1      | 18       | 2011-04-03  | x
4      | 19       | 2009-06-01  | a
8      | 19       | 2009-06-01  | e
```

will select `key_id`s: #`1` and #`4`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.* FROM tbl p
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT t.id, MIN(record_date) AS MinDate
  FROM tbl t
  GROUP BY t.id
) t ON p.id = t.id AND p.record_date = t.MinDate
GROUP BY p.id
```

This code eliminates duplicate `record_date` in case there are same `ids` with same `record_date`. 
If you want duplicates, remove the last line `GROUP BY p.id`.

Answer (score 0):

This a old question, but this can useful for someone
In my case i can't using a sub query because i have a big query and i need using min() on my result, if i use sub query the db need reexecute my big query. i'm using Mysql

```
select t.* 
    from (select m.*, @g := 0
        from MyTable m --here i have a big query
        order by id, record_date) t
    where (1 = case when @g = 0 or @g <> id then 1 else  0 end )
          and (@g := id) IS NOT NULL
```

Basically I ordered the result and then put a variable in order to get only the first record in each group.

Answer (score 0):

The below query takes the first date for each work order (in a table of showing all status changes):

```
SELECT
    WORKORDERNUM,
    MIN(DATE)
FROM
    WORKORDERS
WHERE
    DATE >= to_date('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY
    WORKORDERNUM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    department, 
    min_salary, 
    (select s1.last_name from staff s1 where s1.salary=s3.min_salary ) lastname 
from 
    (select department, min (salary) min_salary from staff s2 group by s2.department) s3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves of the existing answers this question already has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.