# SQL query to get recent items

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a sql table

```
id  item    date
A   apple   2017-09-17
A   banana  2017-08-10
A   orange  2017-10-01
B   banana  2015-06-17
B   apple   2014-06-18
```

How do I write a sql query, so that for each id I get the two most recent items based on date. ex:

```
id  recent second_recent   
a   orange  apple
b   banana  apple
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The answer is different for different systems. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: also - what have you tried? this is not a do it for me site

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  SQL Server and MySQL are not the same thing.

Comment: @SeanLange I am using sql server

Comment: @Randy I wasn't able to come up with a logic on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then item end) as most_recent,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then item end) as most_recent_but_one,
from (select t.*, 
            row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said on:
[SQL: Group by minimum value in one field while selecting distinct rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725168/sql-group-by-minimum-value-in-one-field-while-selecting-distinct-rows)

You must use A group By to get min

```
SELECT mt.*,     
FROM MyTable mt INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT item AS recent, MIN(date) MinDate, ID
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY ID
    ) t ON mt.ID = t.ID AND mt.date = t.MinDate
```

I think you can do the same with a order by to get two value instead of one

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot table

```
SELECT first_column AS <first_column_alias>,
 [pivot_value1], [pivot_value2], ... [pivot_value_n]
 FROM
 (<source_table>) AS <source_table_alias>
 PIVOT
 (
 aggregate_function(<aggregate_column>)
 FOR <pivot_column> IN ([pivot_value1], [pivot_value2], ... [pivot_value_n])
 ) AS <pivot_table_alias>;
```

Learn More with example here
[Example](http://www.treselle.com/blog/pivoting-and-unpivoting-multiple-columns-in-ms-sql-server/)