# Using Orderby before GroupBy in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table that I want to select product_name with lowest/min price the following:

```
product_name | price 
Cat          |   12
Dog          |   21
Cat          |   14
Dog          |   20
Fish         |   10
Fish         |    3
```

THE DESIRE Output should be

```
Cat  | 12
Dog  | 20
Fish | 3
```

BELOW IS MY SQL QUERY

```
$products = DB::table('products')
            ->orderBy('products.products_price', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('products.products_name')
            ->get();
```

When I used this script, it only shows the highest/max price, not the lowest price

Comment: I have not tested this but should simply changing the direction of the sort not achieve what you want? `orderBy('products.products_price', 'desc')`?

Comment: Use 'desc' in query... See what happens.

Comment: I have used 'desc' too but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an aggregate instead of ordering. For Laravel, that means passing in the columns along with a DB::raw:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
        ->orderBy('products.products_price', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('products.products_name')
        ->select(['product_name', DB::raw('min(price) as price')])
        ->get();
```

**Edit for ID**

Taking off the answer here : [SQL: Group by minimum value in one field while selecting distinct rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725168/sql-group-by-minimum-value-in-one-field-while-selecting-distinct-rows) the mysql query would be

```
SELECT p1.*     
FROM products p1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT product_name, MIN(price) AS as min_price
        FROM products
        GROUP BY product_name
    ) p2 ON p1.product_name = p2.product_name AND p1.price = p2.min_price
```

Now we have to convert it to Query Builder

```
$products = DB::table('products AS p1')
   ->join(DB::raw('(
    SELECT product_name, MIN(price) AS as min_price
    FROM products
    GROUP BY product_name
) AS p2'), 
    function($join)
    {
       $join->on('p1.product_name', '=', 'p2.product_name');
       $join->on('p1.price', '=', 'p2.min_price');
    })
    ->get(['p1.id', 'p1.product_name', 'p1.price']);
```

This has not been tested, so I hope it works

Comment: Thanks but this does not bring out the correct product "ID". ie if Cat is ID 1 and 3. The Cat with lowest/min is ID 1. hence the output should be Product ID =1 and Product_name = Cat and Price = 12. The SQL query you advice gave correct product_name  but the product ID is wrong. i.e it use Product ID 3 with MIN price as against Product ID 1 with min

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention the product ID. That adds a new wrinkle

Comment: So sorry. It was when I closely look at the output I discovered. Please help, I've been on this for over 24hrs

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope it helps. Also of note is that Laravel now has [subquery joins](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins) which might help as well

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You are not defining that the price attribute should be aggregated to a minimum.

---

**Solution:**

If you want the max price you need to select the MIN() aggregation.
You can do this by using  `->selectRaw('MIN(price) as max_price')`.

---

**Please Note:**

If you want other attributes also selected simply add them comma separated.

`->selectRaw('name, MAX(price) as max_price')`

**@edit**

Do you still use the oderBy? If not, try it with orderBy('products.products_price', 'ASC')

Comment: Thanks but this does not bring out the correct product "ID". ie if Cat is ID 1 and 3. The Cat with lowest/min is ID 1. hence the output should be Product ID =1 and Product_name = Cat and Price = 12. The SQL query you advice gave correct product_name but the product ID is wrong. i.e it use Product ID 3 with MIN price as against Product ID 1 with min.

Comment: ye the id is not correct, but that was not asked in your question

Comment: @LampSoft look at my edit do you still use the orderBy?